# (Jetpack Compose) How to fix the error with custom TextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I can not do it. One mistake for: `TextField`, `Text`, `IconButton`.
`@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.buildAnnotatedString
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.text.withStyle
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import ru.exemple.app.R
import ru.exemple.app.presentation.components.StandardTextField
import ru.exemple.app.ui.theme.SpaceMedium
import ru.exemple.app.ui.theme.SpaceSmall

@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = SpaceMedium)
                .align(Alignment.Center)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.login)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(SpaceSmall))
            StandardTextField(
                text = viewModel.usernameText.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.setUsernameText(it)
                },
                hint = stringResource(id = R.string.login_hint)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(SpaceSmall))
            StandardTextField(
                text = viewModel.passwordText.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.setPasswordText(it)
                },
                hint = stringResource(id = R.string.password_hint),
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
            )
        }
        Text(
            text = buildAnnotatedString {
                append(stringResource(id = R.string.dont_have_an_account_yet))
                append("")
                val signUpText = stringResource(id = R.string.sign_up)
                withStyle(
                    style = SpanStyle(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
                    )
                ) {
                    append(signUpText)
                }
            },
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        )
    }
}
}
```

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Visibility
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.VisibilityOff
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import ru.exemple.app.R
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

@Composable
fun StandardTextField(
    text: String = "",
    hint: String = "",
    isError: Boolean = false,
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val isPasswordToggleDisplayed by remember {
        mutableStateOf(keyboardType == KeyboardType.Password)
    }

    var isPasswordVisible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        placeholder = {

            Text(text = text)
        },
        isError = isError,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = keyboardType
        ),
        sigleLine = true,
        trailingIcon = {
            if (isPasswordToggleDisplayed) {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = if (isPasswordVisible) {
                            Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
                        } else {
                            Icons.Filled.Visibility
                        },
                        contentDescription = if (isPasswordVisible) {
                            stringResource(id = R.string.password_visible_content_description)
                        } else {

                            stringResource(id = R.string.password_hidden_content_description)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.5'
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.5'
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.5'
    // Material Design
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.5'
    // Material design icons
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.5'
    // Integration with activities
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    // Integration with ViewModels
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07'
    // Integration with observables
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.5'

    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.5'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to figure this out for the last 15 minutes, and couldn't wrap my head around it.

It looks like there was a typo:

```
sigleLine = true,
```

Not sure why it doesn't catch those.

Hope that helped!

Comment: This is very strange, your answer helped me. I'm surprised.